# Android Loadable Kernel Module Error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I got an Android LKM for my HTC Sensation XL as below, it will print a debug message before sys_open called. My OS is Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. Android Kernel is runnymede-crc-2.6.35 downloaded from http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads .

> /*
>   * mydebug.c
>   * System Call sys_open dubugging
>   */
>
> `#include <linux/kernel.h>`
>   `#include <linux/module.h>`
>   `#include <asm/unistd.h>`
>
> `asmlinkage ssize_t (*orig_open)(const char *pathname, int flags);`
>
> `asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_open(const char *pathname, int flags)`
>   `{`
>   `printk(KERN_INFO "SYS_OPEN: %s\n", pathname);`
>   `return orig_open(pathname, flags);`
>   `}`
>
> `static int __init root_start(void)`
>   `{`
>   `unsigned long sys_addr = 0xc003b104;      /* System.map */`
>   `unsigned long *sys_call_table= (unsigned long *)sys_addr;`
>
> `orig_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];`
>   `sys_call_table[__NR_open] = hooked_open;`
>   `return 0;`
>   `}`
>
> `static void __exit root_stop(void)`
>   {
>
> `unsigned long sys_addr = 0xc003b104;`
>   `unsigned long *sys_call_table= (unsigned long *)sys_addr;`
>
> `sys_call_table[__NR_open] = &orig_open;`
>   `}`
>
> `module_init(root_start);`
>   `module_exit(root_stop);`

---

But it shows errors during compiling,

> `make -C /home/scott/runnymede-crc-2.6.35/ M=$(PWD) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- modules`
>   `make[1]: Entering directory '/home/scott/runnymede-crc-2.6.35'`
>   `CC [M]  /home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.o`
>   `cc1: warnings being treated as errors`
>   `/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.c: In function 'root_start':`
>   `/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.c:23: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`
>   `/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.c:24: error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`
>   `/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.c: In function 'root_stop':`
>   `/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.c:34: error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`
>   `make[2]: [/home/scott/workspace/debugkit/mydebug.o] Error 1`
>   `make[1]: [_module_/home/scott/workspace/debugkit] Error 2`
>   `make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/scott/runnymede-crc-2.6.35'`
>   `make: [default] Error 2`

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You defined `sys_call_table` as a pointer to an unsigned long, then do `sys_call_table[1234]`.
The resulting type is an unsigned long. You try to assign a pointer to this.

That's exactly what the compiler is telling you. Either redefine the type of `sys_call_table` or cast the assignment.

Note that replacing syscalls is deeply frowned upon, especially from kernel modules. The fact that you have to do silly things like use a hard coded address from system.map should be taken as a hint that you shouldn't be doing it in the first place.